# Which API_KEY do I use to create new TrueVault users?

Tags: security, truevault

I would like to use the Users API to create new users in TrueVault but it requires an Authorization header with the encoded API KEY. I am unsure about which API key to use for this purpose and where to get it from? Also, Should this be hard coded into the mobile app I'm creating?

Thanks

Comment: hey did you find your solution, if you have done with truevault please help me too.

Comment: Please see selected answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an initial full access User using the console. https://console.truevault.com -> Users -> Create New User. Upon creation, clicking into the User should show the API Key. This User will have full CRUDA privileges on all resources, so it's unsafe to use this User's API Key for an application.

In order to create a User with limited privileges, you should not create a User through the console. You can use the API Key of one of the Users created in the console to create another User using our Users API. Check out https://docs.truevault.com/Users.html to see how to do so.

We recommend using environment variables to represent API Keys or any other sensitive data in your application.